# Jump links, how to jump to next available anchor on page?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, anchor

I am programming a one page web site in wordpress that uses jump links to go to specific anchors on the page. I am doing this by adding a custom walker to wordpress menu that changes menu links to anchors. I want to create a button that jump to the next anchor on the page regardless of what the name of the anchor is. Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is my code so far:

**jQuery for smooth scrolling**

```
$(function() {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {

    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 2000,'swing');
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Walker in functions.php**

```
class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{
  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args){
       global $wp_query;
       $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
       $class_names = $value = '';
       $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
       $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
       $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
       $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';
       $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
       if($item->object == 'page')
       {
            $varpost = get_post($item->object_id);
            if(is_home()){
              $attributes .= ' href="#' . $varpost->post_name . '"';
            }else{
              $attributes .= ' href="'.home_url().'/#' . $varpost->post_name . '"';
            }
       }
       else
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
        $item_output .= $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
 }
```

}

**Calling the walker in wordpress menu**

```
    wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary_navi',
            'echo' => true,
            'walker'=> new Description_Walker,
            'depth' => 4) );
```

**Creating the anchors in Wordpress template**

```
<div id="<?php echo $post->post_name;?>">
```

Comment: The next from what is visible in the view port or the next after the one you clicked last?

Comment: Greetings user###, you are invited to read http://stackoverflow.com/help . Without beeing able to show your own efforts to solve your situation, your question is most likely to be voted-close or down-voted.

Comment: Unless the obviousness of the question does not deem code mandatory.

Comment: I added the code I have been using and updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to code your way out of it for example if tab does not give you enough control, try something like

**Plain JavaScript**

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qtu22/)

```
var lastClicked=0-1,anchors=document.getElementsByTagName("a");

window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("jumpbut").onclick=function() {
    var hash = "";
    for (var i=lastClicked+1;i<anchors.length;i++) {
      if (anchors[i].hash) {
        hash=anchors[i].hash;
        lastClicked=i;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (hash) location.hash=hash;
  } 
}
```

**jQuery**

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/T5FgG/)

```
$(function() {
  var $anchors = $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])'),
      $target = $anchors.first(),
      current=0;
  $("#jumpbut").on("click",function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $target.offset().top
    }, 2000,'swing');
    $target = $anchors.eq(current+1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Now I only need to add the smooth scrolling and we are good. Thanks for the help my good man.

Comment: See update. I would have posted jQuery had you tagged with jQuery or showed some code first

Comment: Thank you mplungjan, you rock!

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing the TAB key. Cool hey ?

You can try using the : [tabindex](http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0101/0101-TABINDEX.html).